# Regex in python, find a range of lengths

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing a regex on a string to find a certain pattern:

```
fileName = '123456_BI12554_AA_0021.jpg'
id = re.findall(r'(_BI\d{5}_)', fileName)
```

Which finds `_BI12554_` but sometimes there are 6 digits and not just 5.

Is there a way to find all the digits between `_BI` and `_` regardless of how many there are?

Comment: why not `re.findall(r'(_BI\d+_)', fileName)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes of course: you can use `+` to mean "1 or more" digits.

```
re.findall(r'(_BI\d+_)', fileName)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 3):

If you know that it's either going to be 5 or 6, you can make a slight modification in your pattern to allow for this:

```
import re

fileNames = ['123456_BI12554_AA_0021.jpg', '123456_BI125546_AA_0021.jpg']
for fileName in fileNames:
    print(re.findall(r'(_BI\d{5,6}_)', fileName))
#_BI12554_
#_BI125546_
```

Here the notation `\d{5,6}` means match between 5 and 6 digits (inclusive).

Answer (score 2):

You need to just use `\d+` which checks for one or more occurrence of digit.

For example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(_BI\d+_)', '123456_BI12554_AA_0021.jpg')
['_BI12554_']
>>> re.findall(r'(_BI\d+_)', '123456_BI125548487387378378_AA_0021.jpg')
['_BI125548487387378378_']
>>> re.findall(r'(_BI\d+_)', '123456_BI1_AA_0021.jpg')
['_BI1_']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a positive lookbehind `(?<=`: and then one or more digits `\d+`

[`(?<=_BI)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/EO4heT/)

That would give you all the digits between _BI and _.

Use [`_BI\d+_`](https://regex101.com/r/PSCgBy/1) to select from `_BI`, one or more digits `\d+` and the next underscore `_`